# Why sleep after creating a tar.gz file

Tags: linux, bash, sleep

I am reviewing linux bash scripts that are intended to make hourly backups of a directory and copy that backup to another server.  The scripts are run by `cron`.  They all follow the same general code path like this:

```
cd /path/to/parent/directory
tar -zcvf data_backup.tar.gz data
sleep 10
# scp file to server
```

I am wondering what is the reason for the `sleep 10` command.  I understand that it will cause the process to stop for 10 seconds, but why would the author have put this in the first place?  I would assume that after the `tar` command completed, then the file would be properly flushed to disk and the scp command could execute without errors.

These scripts are running on CentOS 6 & CentOS 7 systems.  The person who wrote the scripts has left the organization, so I am unable to contact him.

Comment: Ask the developer

Comment: Even if the file wasn't synced to disk, the scp command could proceed.

Comment: Create a test machine and try it without the sleep period?  My guess is it's a crude attempt to protect the new files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would assume that after the tar command completed, then the file
>   would be properly flushed to disk and the scp command could execute
>   without errors

You are correct in that assumption, and I would expect that `sleep` command to be redundant.

Comment: Thanks!  I was guessing that it was redundant, but I am not familiar with the inner workings of linux to be sure.  I appreciate it!